# Ambiguous notation for squared matrix

Tags: matrices, notation

What does $A^{2}$  mean for square $A$? Is it $AA$  or $AA^{T}$? Sometimes, the result may differ.

Or there is no uniform approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no ambiguity, $A^2=AA$, period.

Comment: Thank you. Could you answer another short question: Is 0 (zero matrix) considered as projection operator? (It satisfies 0^2=0)

Comment: Yes, trivially so.  It's the projection onto a $0$-dimensional subspace.  In fact, it would also be an orthogonal projection.

Comment: @John I guess that would depend on the definition, but usually yes,  $0_{n\times n}$ is a projection.

Comment: @John You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

When we define $A^2$, we have an operation such as multiplication or addition on real number and for shorthand we let $3\times 3 = 3^2$, $3\times 3 \times 3 = 3^3$ or $3+3=2 \times 3$, $3+3+3 = 3 \times 3$ and so on